# How much the wealth inequality increased in the USA in the last decades?

Tags: inequality, wealth

Are there any studies trying to measure the increase of the wealth inequality in the USA?

Say for example how much it increased, comparing with 1990. Or compared with any other moment in time after 1970.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> This statistic shows the Gini coefficient, an index for measuring
>   income distribution, for U.S. households from 1990 to 2016. A Gini
>   coefficient of zero expresses perfect equality, where all would have
>   the same income,a Gini coefficient of one expresses maximal inequality
>   among values. In 2016, the Gini coefficient for household income was
>   0,48. This is an increase since 1990 of 0.5 points, indicating an
>   increase of income inequality in the United States.

Source: [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/219643/gini-coefficient-for-us-individuals-families-and-households/)

In case you are interested in *how* data for such indeces are gathered, a recent study explaining its data process is [Wealth Inequality in the United States since 1913](https://academic.oup.com/qje/article-abstract/131/2/519/2607097).

Comment: Thanks, do you have some wealth inequality data too? A worker might be able to save only 100 USD per month, while another one having a wage two times bigger can save even 1000 USD - that's ten times more. Therefore the wealth inequality should look much worse than income inequality (in this case 10 is much greater than 2). I know it's hard to measure wealth when the rich are saving their money in tax havens but maybe someone tried though

Comment: @JoeJobs You could try http://wid.world/country/usa/ (The second graph.)